# Measurability of limit function into a Polish space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The exercise is to show that if $(X,\mathscr A)$ is a measurable space, and $f_n:X\to Y$ where $Y$ is Polish, $n\in \mathbb N,$ and $f_n$ are measurable, then $f=\lim f_n$ is measurable (presumably with respect to $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B(Y)$; this is not specified). The hint is to prove that $L=\left \{ x:\lim f(x)\ \text {exists} \right \}$ is contained in $\mathscr A$. Here is my attempt. I am pretty sure of the first part, but there is a problem with the second.

Define for $i,j\in \mathbb N,\ F_{ij}(x)=(f_i(x),f_j(x)).$ Since $\mathscr B(Y\times Y)=\mathscr B(Y)\times \mathscr B(Y)$ because $Y$ is Polish, the $F_{ij}$ are measurable. It follows then that $d\circ F_{ij}$ are measurable, where $d$ is the complete metric on $Y.$ It now follows that for fixed $i,j,n$, the sets $A^{n}_{ij}:=\left \{ x:d(f_i(x),f_j(x))<1/n \right \}$ are measurable, so that $L=\cap_{n}\cup_k\cap_{i\ge k}\cap_{j\ge k}A^{n}_{ij}\in \mathscr A.$

To show that $f$ is measurable, first note that the trace $\mathscr S=\left \{ A\cap L:A\in \mathscr A \right \}$ is a sigma-algebra so now if take an arbitrary continuous function $g:Y\to \mathbb R$ and observe that for $x\in L$ we have  $g\circ f=\lim g\circ f_n=\limsup g\circ f_n,\ $ from which it follows that $f$ is measurable with respect to $\mathscr S$ and $\mathscr B(Y)$, but this is not exactly what we want.